# set proxy in matlab

Tags: matlab, proxy

I want to set proxy server settings in matlab. I know my proxy configuration URL which I have put in my mozilla firefox's automatic proxy configuration URL  (which works fine), but Matlab is asking for proxy host and port.
How can I find that ? I only know proxy configuration URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure so complex situations as in firefox.

Point your browser to the configuration URL. It should show you some text. 
Pick the one line that "describes" the connection you want to make best.
Typically near the end there is a statement `RETURN "PROXY ....";` - this is the *default* so quite likely you want this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99719-how-can-i-configure-my-proxy-server-settings-within-matlab) article, in MATLAB you can set the proxy as follows:

```
1) Launch MATLAB
2) Select the "Home" tab
3) Select "Preferences"
4) Select "Web"
5) Check the box labeled "Use a proxy server to connect to the Internet"
6) Fill in your proxy information
7) If authentication is necessary, check the box labeled "Use a proxy with authentication" and fill in the appropriate information
8) Use the "Test connection" button to verify that the information entered was correct
NOTE: Only R2008b and newer has the ability to test the proxy connection and enter authentication information.
```